# How do I add a delete function in my cart in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## the cart controller - im having trouble declaring the delete function

```
class CartController < ApplicationController

def add
id = params[:id]

cart = session[:cart] ||= {}
cart[id] = (cart[id] || 0) + 1

redirect_to :action => :index
end

def index
@cart = session[:cart] || {}
end

end
```

## the main item page - the link to delete the item is already defined, I'm confused in the controller part

```
<h1 id="prodhead">Products</h1>


<table class="catalog">

<% for item in @items %>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="image">
        <%= link_to (image_tag item.image_url), item %>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="title">
        <%= link_to item.title, item %>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <%=h item.description %>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <% if session[:login] == 1 %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit Item', edit_item_path(item) %> |
            ***<%= link_to 'Delete Item', item, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method =>   :delete %>***
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Add to Cart", :controller => :cart, :action => :add, :id => item %><br />
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="price"> 
        <%= number_to_currency(item.price, :unit => "&dollar;") %>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>

<% end %>

</table>


<% if session[:login] == 1 %>
<p><%= link_to 'New item', new_item_path %></p>

<% end %>
```

## The Routes.rb -  the route for deleting is also defined already

```
OnlineShop::Application.routes.draw do
get "cart/index"

get "cart/add"

get "cart/checkout"

get "cart/del"

get "site/about"

get "site/contact"

get "user/admin_login"

get "user/logout"

resources :items
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all I've notice you reposted your issue however this time somewhat more descriptive, please for future issues, think before you create a ticket and take the time to edit previous tickets which need refining to keep the community clean.

OT:
I see you've created item and cart resources with basic CRUD functionality however the way you did it is not quite "The rails way" I suggest you start a project bij using the scaffold command to learn how this CRUD and routes should be implemented.

If you are willing to learn more about the topic I advice reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Also I've noticed you use the "h" syntax to escape your output this is only done before Rails 2.3.8 may I suggest using a newer rails version when starting out?